# Can generic laptop battery charger ruin my original battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, charger

I want to use 2 power adapters for my laptop, one I keep in the bag, and one I keep at home.

One is original, and other one is generic brand.

They both work fine, same thing, generic one charges fine, doesn't overheat.

My question is, can the generic one damage the battery on the new laptop?

Comment: No likely if it has good quality and the same or higher specs than the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the voltage is precisely the same as the OEM adapter and supplies at least as much power. Then you should not have issues.

That said, I have two (for your reasons) and they are both OEM. No issues.